# Unable to synchronously open file (file signature not found) when loading a Deep Learning model in streamlit

Tags: python, github

I am coming to you asI couldn't find a solution to my problem, I was able to build a `DL` model and save it in `h5` format (70 MB) that I stored in `GitHub`, and I tried deploying it in `streamlit` by using a Python code that calls the model for prediction butI get this error :

[image],

Your help would be much appreciated, and if there are any other details I should add, please let me know, here is a snapshot of my python code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRtBz.png)

I have tried many things like this link: https://www.answeroverflow.com/m/1179035982801141790

Comment: Please post the code as a text, ant an screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You might have used git lfs to upload .h5 file. This might have caused the error.

Solution:

1. You can simply deploy your model on google cloud as google cloud function (https://youtu.be/ra4j7yDlakQ?si=JJ1SQAL4BowSyUun).
2. Then use chatgpt to edit streamlit main.py file so as to process image using google cloud function url.
   sample code (edit as per your need):

```
import streamlit as st
import requests

# upload file
file = st.file_uploader('', type=['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'])

# Function to make predictions using the Cloud Function URL
def predict_image(image):
    # Send a request to the Cloud Function URL with the image data
    cloud_function_url = "YOUR_CLOUD_FUNCTION_URL"
    response = requests.post(cloud_function_url, files={"file": image})
    
    # Parse the response JSON
    prediction = response.json()
    
    return prediction

# display image and make prediction
if file is not None:
    image = file.read()
    st.image(image, use_column_width=True)

    # classify image using the Cloud Function
    prediction = predict_image(image)

    # write classification
    predicted_class = prediction.get('predicted_class', 'Unknown')
    confidence = prediction.get('confidence', 0.0)
    st.write('<h2 style="color: white;">Predicted Disease: {}</h2>'.format(predicted_class), unsafe_allow_html=True)
    st.write('<h3 style="color: white;">Confidence score: {}%</h3>'.format(int(confidence * 100)), unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

3. Remember to write main.py code for google cloud function in such a way that it will take input from streamlit app and return result.
   sample code (edit as per your need):

```
from google.cloud import storage
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import io

model = None
class_names = [ ]

BUCKET_NAME = ""  # Replace with your GCP bucket name

def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name):
    """Downloads a blob from the bucket."""
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)

    blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)

    print(f"Blob {source_blob_name} downloaded to {destination_file_name}.")

def predict(request):
    global model
    if model is None:
        download_blob(
            BUCKET_NAME,
            "models/training.h5",
            "/tmp/training.h5",
        )
        model = tf.keras.models.load_model("/tmp/training.h5")

    # Ensure the request has a file named "file"
    if "file" not in request.files:
        return {"error": "No file found in the request."}, 400

    # Read image from request
    image = request.files["file"].read()
    
    # Convert image data to PIL Image
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image)).convert("RGB").resize((256, 256))

    # Convert PIL Image to numpy array
    image_array = np.array(image) / 255.0  # Normalize image

    # Expand dimensions to match model input shape
    image_array = np.expand_dims(image_array, axis=0)

    # Make prediction
    predictions = model.predict(image_array)
    predicted_class = class_names[np.argmax(predictions[0])]
    confidence = round(float(np.max(predictions[0]) * 100), 2)

    return {"predicted_class": predicted_class, "confidence": confidence}
```